# AngularJs + (Spring MVC ou Especificacao)

Tags: java, angularjs, spring-mvc, spring-security

Galera,

Estou iniciando o desenvolvimento de um sistema (java), e estou com duvida sobre a tecnologia. O sistema é totalmente restrito (login/senha) e vai ser disponibilizado na internet, logo preciso de segurança. Conheço um pouco de AngularJs e queria utilizar o mesmo pela facilidade. Sendo assim, pensei em utilizar o AngularJs + Spring MVC + Spring Security. No meu pensamento eu prefiro o Spring por conta do modulo de segurança (tenho certa experiência), inclusive já fiz testes e consegui colocar segurança nos serviços rest sem muito trabalho. A minha duvida é que algumas pessoas acham isso desnecessário, preferem fazer a camada de front com angular totalmente desacoplada do servidor e implementar a segurança de forma manual, ou seja, criar algo manual mesmo para tratar os usuários autorizados (sessão), e assim proteger o sistema/serviços, essa seria a solução AngularJs + JEE (rest). Essa ultima solução seria baseada em criação de tokens (ou algo assim) de forma manual e tratar tanto no angular como nos serviços rest, porém a principio acho esse tratamento mais complexo e propenso a falhas, o spring do meu ponto de vista ja traz isso pronto. Qual a opnião de vocês? Também preferem a camada de front totalmente desacoplada? Ou alguma sugestão (esquecer angular e partir apenas de spring mvc por exemplo)?

Vou rodar o projeto em um servidor JEE completo. A aplicação terá níveis de usuários, ou seja, algumas paginas e serviços só podem ser acessados por um usuário com perfil administrador por exemplo.

Obs: Meu conhecimento de Spring MVC não é muito amplo, mas já fiz coisas básicas e me pareceu bem simples.

Grato.

Comment: Cara eu não conheço Spring e faço por tokens mesmo. Quando faço login no sistema o back-end(Java) gera um token e envia esse pro front. Eu armazeno esse token em algum lugar e a cada requisição tenho um interceptador no back-end que fica esperando esse token e verifica se o mesmo é valido. Cada sessão tem um token, eu achei legal implementar essa solução.

Comment: Obrigado @Techies!